# How does Asp.Net MVC compare to Java MVC frameworks

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've started my career as a Java developer, then moved to Asp.NET and recently to the Asp.Net MVC, which I like a lot. When developing in Java I used Struts1, which I remember as a hideous framework with loads of XML. Now I suspect that Java MVC frameworks have moved on from the Struts times. So how do modern Java MVC frameworks compare to the ASP.Net MVC? Which one of them is the most similar to the Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: This should probably be community wiki. I think you should refine your question as much as possible too, otherwise it may get closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Play](http://www.playframework.org/) is very good example of MVC framework. Even more then convension-over-configuration principle i like its short edit-run cycle. Another good example of MVC framework on JVM with short edit-run cycle is [Grails](http://www.grails.org/), though it's for Groovy langauge, not Java itself.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of Asp.Net MVC compared to java frameworks is the simplicity that is achieved through convention over configuration

**Edit:** I had a look into http://www.playframework.org/ and it looks quiet simple just like Asp.Net mvc.

Comment: I did some search on java mvc framework and most of them uses xml files for configuration.

Comment: take a look at http://www.playframework.org/ . Also Tapestry does not require a lot of configuration

Comment: Yeah, play framework looks nice, although it doesn't seem to be very popular yet. @Alexey if you made it an answer instead of a comment I could accept it ;)